# Why is a closing "Thank you" deemed unprofessional?

Tags: discussion

I know in the grand scheme this is incredibly minor, however it really bothers me.

I do 99% of my coding in relation to solution and tool building for an IT department. As a result of writing AND using said code to troubleshoot/fix IT-related issues I approach asking questions on Stack Overflow with the same mentality I do my job.

When I post I strive to always have three things in my post.

1. Details, details, and details.

   From a troubleshooting prospective, of which I do daily, nothing is more infuriating than a "<Blank> does not work." or a "Computer's BROKEN!" or "Email!" (for the IT crowd fans out there). As a result, unless my question is so simple that it needs little to no details, my post will always have as much details as I can think of, e.g. code, explanations, screenshots, etc.
2. Organization and flow.

   I admittedly have a nigh OCD level of being anal retentive and I will read through the preview of my post over and over again making edits until I am satisfied that what I am sending looks and reads well. I will, 100% guaranteed, have read through this very question several times before hitting Post Your Question.
3. Be Courteous.

   Working in IT I have the customer service mentality with things, e.g. being polite, tactful, patient, and most importantly when I MYSELF am on the receiving end of such customer service to be thankful.

I do not at all understand how expressing a small amount of gratitude for the help someone else gave or will give to fix YOUR problem makes you somehow unprofessional, or less professional. Not only don't I not understand it, I completely disagree with that notion.

I strive everyday to be as professional as possible, and I am proud to say I have earned the respect and accolades of my peers and end users through both my useful and well crafted coding solutions, as well as how I carry and communicate with others.

I help solve peoples' issues, and I write code to make the rest of the IT staff's jobs exponentially easier. I love it! It gives me a great sense of accomplishment. That being said, when I need help, when I need someone to take time out of their busy professional lives to give me a hand, the LEAST I can do is offer a small amount of gratitude, humility, and respect to them. And I don't think at all this detracts from being professional. I dare say it adds an element sorely lacking in professionalism.

Comment: One word: Noise!

Comment: What I do when someone has given me valuable information on Stack Overflow or another Stack Exchange site, and I am so happy I *have* to thank them, is leave a comment. Comments are second class citizens, designed to be temporary, and it's much more appropriate to have *some* amount of personal communication there - used very sparingly, though.

Comment: Like good code, good Q/A's should have nothing but what's needed. Thank with votes/accepts.

Comment: You may also be interested in [Why is it considered rude to say "thanks in advance"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98149)

Comment: (For a real diff, use "side-by-side markdown", not the default "inline".)

Answer (score 27):

> Why is a closing “Thank you” deemed unprofessional?

Because Stack Overflow strives (imperfectly, flawedly, yet constantly) to be an encyclopedia, not a forum.

Comment: *"This"*...so much!

Comment: The nature of if being a question and answer system makes it inherently NOT an encyclopedia. You don't see Encyclopdia Britanica setup as such. There have as far as my experience never been much questions in any encyclopedia I have used, just facts. And are people SO exasperated that a short one sentence thank you at the end of an otherwise well thought  out and detailed question makes them see red? I'm sorry but that seems like a VERY stressful way to live life and an especially stressful way to work. IMHO

Comment: @TofuBug "an encyclopedia-like repository of information useful far beyond the current asker and answerers", then. It's arguing over semantics, though. You understand what I mean. `And are people SO exasperated` exasperated? Not really, I think. We just edit stuff out

Comment: Encyclopedia Britannica uses the old fashioned stuck-in-the-mud style of putting an encyclopedia together.  If you consult it for an article that doesn't exist then it will take a letter and at least a year or two to get an answer.  Not the way we are doing it of course.  That we are doing it differently does not mean that adding noise to an article is sensible as well.  It is not.

Comment: EVERY time I see edits related to this, NOT ONCE is the reason; JUST the FACTS, because, Encyclopedia! The reason is always some variation of "it's unprofessional" THAT is why I asked this question. I have no problem changing for a valid reason (Encyclopedia makes sense => I will change) However, when all the reason I'm given seems to be someones Jaded view of what they think professionalism is. I can't help but think that person is just a jerk pushing their opinion on me, and I .refuse to compromise my views for people who act like that. Give me sound LOGICAL reasoning and i'll comply.

Comment: @TofuBug I don't think it's unprofessional to say thank you; in fact I considered not quoting your question in my answer because you specifically ask about that. We just don't *want* thank yous for the reason stated above. I say "thank you" all the time in all my other communication... now sometimes the people enforcing the rule are going to be jerks, nothing we can do about that. The rule still stands and makes sense, IMO.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I completely agree. To be honest didn't know much about the standards., usually if I'm on here asking a question it's because I have exhausted all avenues of trying to fix it myself and it's something i need answered sooner than later so taking the time to read through the standards was never highest on the priorities. That's why i'm thankful for getting to discuss something like this during some down time. I thrive on learning, but I want to know the logical HOW & WHY more than anything (opinions matter little to me) and I extend that want to things like documentation standards too.

Comment: Re "... to be an encyclopedia, not a forum": Or perhaps one could say we are not in the business of ***sending letters*** between one person and another (or a few) (where such formality is expected), like email, BBS, Usenet and forums are/were more or less modelled on.

Comment: @tofu Some people don't really understand the *reasons* behind the site's various guidelines, they just know what the guidelines are. Because they have to put *something* in the edit summary box, they make up a reason. "Unprofessional" is the best they could come up with. It is, as you point out, not entirely accurate. There's nothing "unprofessional" about saying "thank you", it is just not the SO way. As others said, we're building an encyclopedic-style Q&A site, where the focus is on questions and answers, not on individuals or having conversations. It's a bit too long for an edit summary.

Comment: @CodyGray I have a really hard time just doing something because that's what I was told. For instance, whenever I have to look up code for something I never Ctrl+V it right in. I have this obsessive need to tear it apart and understand it enough to rebuild it myself BEFORE I ever use it in my code. I approach documentation standards the same way.